# Is Site Percolation with Bernoulli variables i.i.d. independent and identically distributed?

Tags: probability, terminology, inclusion-exclusion, percolation, reliability

I cannot understand the `identically distributed` part in the  i.i.d assumption. Consider a site percolation where each event is a Bernoulli variable. Does this mean that each event is independent of each other? Do I need to check some conditions to make sure this assumption is valid?

I am interested in two-terminal reliabily that is the probability that two terminals are connected by some path.

*Example.*

> When I calculate the reliability over the Bernoulli variables, does the inclusion-exclusion formula becomes just a $\pm$sum without intersection terms?
>
> [image]

**Is a site percolation with Bernoulli variables i.i.d. or what does it mean to be identically distributed?**

Comment: "so each event is independent of each other" This is an additional assumption, not a consequence of these events being described by Bernoulli random variables. Also, it would probably help to define reliability here.

Comment: @DPoole ok then my implication is wrong, I tried to describe the fact that each site is a Bernoulli variable. Eg. two-terminal reliability is the probability that two terminals are connected by some path. For multisource multiterminal realibily, things can be different. The focus is on understanding the Bernoulli variables as you commented I may be misunderstanding the i.i.d.